# Split, find and iterate over output of command

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I currently have the following bash command:

```sh
cargo metadata | jq .workspace_members[]
```

And it returns something like the following:

```
"module1 0.1.0 (path+file:///workspace/module1)"
"module2 0.1.0 (path+file:///workspace/nested/module2)"
"module3 0.1.0 (path+file:///workspace/nested/module3)"
```

I would like to split the string/stream/input by new lines and find (using the regexp `path\+file\:(.*)\)`) the file path on each line. And then be able to iterate over them:

```sh
for path in strings; do
   echo "$path"
done
```

Which would then print out the paths:

```
///workspace/module1
///workspace/nested/module2
///workspace/nested/module3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the paths using just `jq`, with its regular expression based `match` filter:

```sh
$ cargo metadata | jq -r '.workspace_members[] | match("(?<=path\\+file:)[^)]+") | .string'
///workspace/module1
///workspace/nested/module2
///workspace/nested/module3
```

To iterate over them in a `bash` loop:

```sh
while read -r path; do
    # Something with $path
done < <(cargo metadata | jq -r '.workspace_members[] | match("(?<=path\\+file:)[^)]+") | .string')
```

or save the lines in an array

```sh
readarray -t paths < <(cargo metadata | jq -r '.workspace_members[] | match("(?<=path\\+file:)[^)]+") | .string')
```